# Is there an excel formula that determines whether a number is "stacking" or not?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help with developing an Excel formula that determines whether or not a 4-digit number has "stacking" digits (digits that are higher than the last e.g. 1234, 2356, 5679) without any duplicates of the digits. For instance, if I type in 4567 in a cell, then the formula would suggest that this is a "stacking" number through a 0 or 1 output (0 = no, 1 = yes). This is with the assumption that digits range from 0-9 and the first digit can be a zero. I've been searching for solutions for a while but unfortunately I have not found any.

If you can also find a formula that does the same thing but for 4-digit numbers with 3 recurring digits and 1 stacking digit (e.g. 3334, 7779, 4555), or 2 recurring digits with 2 stacking digits (e.g. 2234, 3455, 4556), or 2 pairs of recurring digits that do stack (e.g. 3344, 6688, 2288) then please also let me know.

Comment: Instead of searching, have you tried writing a formula, and testing it?

Comment: Or write a VBA macro? Or use a scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365, you can use:

```
=AND(--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1),1)<--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1,,2),1))
```

or

```
=AND(--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1),1)<=--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1,,2),1))
```

The first will show TRUE for stacked digits that do not repeat.
 The second for stacked digits that may repeat.

If you don't have the `SEQUENCE` function you can use:

```
=AND(--MID(L1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(L1)-1)),1)<--MID(L1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,2):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(L1))),1))

=AND(--MID(L1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(L1)-1)),1)<=--MID(L1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,2):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(L1))),1))
```

**Algorithm**

- `MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1),1` returns an array of the first `N-1` characters
- `MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1,,2),1))` returns an array of the last `N-1` characters
- So to detect the kinds of patterns you are looking for, it is merely a matter of comparing the two arrays.

Using the `LET` function since the logic is more clear:

***Stacked digits only***

```
=LET(x,--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1),1),
     y,--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1,,2),1),
     AND(x<y))
```

***Stacked with or without pairs***
***Could be all the same***

```
=LET(x,--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1),1),
     y,--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1,,2),1),
     AND(x<=y))
```

***Stacked but MUST have at least one pair***
***Exclude all the same***

```
=LET(x,--MID(L2,SEQUENCE(LEN(L2)-1),1),
           y,--MID(L2,SEQUENCE(LEN(L2)-1,,2),1),
           AND(x<=y,OR(x=y),OR(x<y)))
```

And I'm sure you can think of other variations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver. I want to ask one final favour though, your =AND(--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1),1)<=--MID(L1,SEQUENCE(LEN(L1)-1,,2),1)) formula for stacked digits that may repeat, also takes into account non-repeating numbers. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: @JasonLover See my edit.

Comment: @JasonLover If my answer is what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I've encountered problems using the stacks only formula. When numbers are 0001-0009, the equation comes out with a "#CALC!" error since there's only 1 digit. Initially I tried to make the "#CALC!" error appear as FALSE with the IF function since it is 3 recurring 0s, but this didn't work. How do you remove this error?

Comment: @JasonLover That is because you are storing those values as **Numbers**.  The Number `0001` is, arithmetically, the number `1` and that is how Excel stores numeric data.  If you want to treat values with leading zero's as text, you will need to enter them as text. You can do this either by pre-formatting the cell as Text, or by preceding the string of digits with a single quote. *(The single quote is a `prefixCharacter` and will not appear in the cell)*.  You could also use the `TEXT` function, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: I find it interesting that the text operations are probably faster than using maths to seperate 1's 10's 100's and 1000's with e.g. '=QUOTIENT(MOD(A1,100),10)' for 10's. I guess it makes sense as the numbers as displayed ob screen are actually natively text and not binary. I have been wondering though if there is some clever maths trick or formula that can be applied to solve this, say 9999-A1 or A1*10-A1 followed by so bit ORs and ANDs. Also thought of maybe using the new LAMBDA function for a recursive solution?

Comment: BTW you can zero buffer e.g. 10 to 0010 using '=REPT("0",4-LEN(A1))&A1' or use the '=TEXT(A1,”0000″)'

Comment: @Mobus I don't have the Lambda function so can't comment on that.  As written (and given text input), the length of the digits string is unconstrained.

Comment: Sadly I don't have 365 either, but LAMBDA is the coolest function since sliced bread (pivot tables?). Its supposedly _the_ function to finally make Excel turing complete. Could name "Stacking" as `=LAMBDA(A, IF(A<100, MOD(A, 10) > QUOTIENT(A, 10), AND(Stacking(QUOTIENT(A, 10)), Stacking(MOD(A, 100)))))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force formula, verifying the total length and comparing each digit sequentially:

```
=(LEN(A1)=4)*(--LEFT(A1,1)<--MID(A1,2,1))*(--MID(A1,2,1)<--MID(A1,3,1))*(--MID(A1,3,1)<RIGHT(A1,1))
```

[image]

Multiplying the Booleans is equivalent to using an AND() expression.